# Gulp is not injecting js files into index.html

Tags: angularjs, gulp, inject, gulp-inject

When I run the my task it says files are injected to index.html in the console; but there is no js files injected in the index.html file actually.

my task functions is as follow

```js
gulp.task('testing', function() {
  gulp.src('../dist/app/index.html')
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(inject(gulp.src('../dist/app/js/*.js', {read: false}), {relative: true}))
  .pipe(debug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../dist/app/js'));
});
```

I am using gulp3.9.1 and gulp-inject version 3.0.0, any help is advance appreciated.

Comment: Comparing this to my setup, my gulp.src files are in an array, try: ...`gulp.src(['../dist/app/js/*.js'],` ... (I'm not sure, but this is easy to try.)

Comment: We will need to see the relevant part of your html as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the destination path specified points to js directory '../dist/app/**js**'
See if the new file is in **js** folder. If yes, you probably don't want **/js** part in the path

Also you can try to add

```
<!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

into you index.html at the place where you want your js scripts to be injected